# best way to receive a USD wire transfer without a US account?

Tags: money-transfer, currency, international-transfer

I'm based in the UK and want to receive some money from a US company called Fidelity.

Last year I set up a transferwise 'borderless' account, which worked really well.  I had a virtual US account, to which I could receive wire transfers from Fidelity.

However, Transferwise recently made a change - from this year, the destination account name for wire transfers must be "Transferwise FBO [my name]" instead of just "[my name]".

Fidelity don't like that, so I'm back to square one.

Are there any other providers?

I tried Payoneer, but they don't support wire transfers, and Fidelity only support wire transfers.

Comment: Drat. Fidelity UK split from Fidelity US in 1980.

Answer (score 5):

It turned out that the best way was to open a dollar account with a UK bank.  I went with Lloyds, and now have a international USD account based on the Isle of Man, which is very cheap to run.